# Is the World Chess Blitz Championship for Robots going to be broadcast over the Internet?

Tags: blitz, engines

Does anyone know if the [World Chess Blitz Championship for Chess Robots](http://www.chessblog.com/2012/05/world-chess-blitz-championship-among.html) in Moscow is going to be streamed over the web? Sounds really cool and I'd like to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears unlikely given it does not even appear that there's a website for the event, just press releases that were posted to weblogs like the one you linked too. Here's [archival video of "Vladimir Kramnik vs Robot"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51b10w3nTS4) for anyone interested in viewing the game play; just in case you thought a robot play a person is boring, [**watch the robot "attack" Kramnik, he almost loses his hand**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51b10w3nTS4#t=2m45s).

Comment: I sent an email to a contact at Moscow Chess and got a reply that said they were not able to broadcast live but will be posting videos of the event soon.

Comment: +1 @Desroska: Hope this year the camera doesn't act all crazy; video linked to above has very odd "special" effects added. Awesome job emailing Moscow Chess!

Comment: Here is a link to the first match. They even had a mime there in the crowd!? http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=TFeXUjQ87Ps

Comment: Here is a better link with all the videos: http://chess-king.com/konstantin-kosteniuks-chesska-is-2012-world-robot-champion.html#more-818